# How to get rid of red and blue lines in Libre Office 5 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice

There is such case, i use hour reporter on my work. It looks like Excel file with row and colloms. This file originally was downloaded from Windows machine to Google Drive and eventually when i downloaded this file to my Ubuntu and opened it i saw red and blue lines

[image]

But if i try again download this file to windows it is good... Without any annoing lines...

How i can get rid of it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don' t see red and blue lines?

Comment: me neither. Also xslx is not fully compatible with LibreOffice and odx is not fully compatible with Excel. You either live with it, use same software to edit the file on all machines or you only use functions and layouts both programs can handle (hard to say, needs experience and deep knowledge of odt and docx resp. odx and xslx.

Comment: @JacobVlijm what do you mean - you don't see lines? Don't you see red lines on right side of picture that i attached and blue lines on left side of picture?

Comment: @mondjunge yes it is the best way to use it on the same OS , but  i bellive that there is have to be compatibility with Windows OS and Ubuntu... Maybe can you suggest something?

Comment: Wording might be confusing, if you mention *lines*, I wouldn' t expect *rectangles*. Isn' t that simply a matter of setting cell background?

Comment: @JacobVlijm no, it is macros , because in normal work if i put wrong value inside cell it pain in red color... but when i open this file on Ubuntu regardless of value it is anyway red... i don't know from what it depends on...